# How to iterate through CSV file URL call PYTHON

Tags: python, json, csv, python-requests, get

I have a file (urls.csv) with 1 Million+ Urls. Each row is a new url like:

1. https://example.com/1
2. https://example.com/2
   And so on....

I would like to get the json file that is at the end of each of these urls and save it as a separate json file for each url with the file name being in sequential order 1,2,3,n...

Here's what I have so far:

```
import requests
import csv

url = []

with open('urls.csv') as csvfile:    
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)    
    for row in csvReader:        
        url.append(row[0])

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

with open('outputfile.json', 'wb') as outf:
    outf.write(response.content)
```

How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
import csv

urls = []

with open('urls.csv') as csvfile:    
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)    
    for row in csvReader:        
        urls.append(row[0])

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    with open(f'{filename}.json', 'wb') as outf:
        outf.write(response.content)
```

So let's say your 3rd urls is `https://example.com/3`, the code will save a file named `3.json` for the corresponding response.